# Windows Phone 10 - crash on adding contact

Tags: nokia-lumia-930

Everytime when i try to add a new contact, i get a crash to main menu.
What can i do to fix this? Obviously this is a heavy bug because it is very important to add new contacts.

Is it possible to hack the contacts into the phone somehow?

Comment: Are you using an insider build? If so, do you know which one?

Comment: I don't know, how can i find out?

Comment: He meant, did you install your os via windows insider app or not?

Comment: I used some app to install windows 10, but it was nothing with the word insider in the name.

Comment: was it upgrade advisor?

Comment: yes i think it was upgrade advisor, i cant tell for sure because my app name was in german afaik, i already uninstalled it directly after the upgrade so i cant tell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by resetting my smartphone while i still had windows 10, after the reset i still had windows 10 but without all the described bugs.

Comment: It is advised to mark your reply as an answer. Else your question will be left unanswered.

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure you are on the latest build (either threshold or redstone). If yes, soft reset your phone. Check if you got any updates for people app in store. If the bug's still present, am afraid you'll have to reset your phone!

And yes, you can add contacts to your device through an app called [Transfer My data](https://www.microsoft.com/store/apps/9wzdncrfj3dr) via Bluetooth or from a .csv file in the SD card.

Comment: Im not sure if i am on the latest build, but if i search for updates then i get that everything is up to date

Comment: Upgrade to latest build 10586.318. or u could just use "Transfer My data" app